# iPhone App crashing after adding and removing an interface class

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt

While I was working on my app, I decided to add an interface builder file (with its class). After giving me problems, I decided it would be better if I get rid of it and program the interface programmatically. After doing so and returning the app to what it was, my app crashes on startup. The error that I get is in this location in Thread 1:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
```

and I get a SIGABRT in the third line in this code snippet:

```
0x34333324:  mov    r12, #328
0x34333328:  svc    #128
0x3433332c:  blo    0x34333344               ; __pthread_kill + 32
0x34333330:  ldr    r12, [pc, #4]
0x34333334:  ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
0x34333338:  b      0x34333340               ; __pthread_kill + 28
0x3433333c:  andeq  r5, r0, r0, ror #25
0x34333340:  bx     r12                      
0x34333344:  bx     lr
```

Please note that the app works fine on the iphone simulator 5.1, so I'm not quite sure what's going on. I have a feeling adding an interface class then removing it caused this, but I can't really find the root of the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any console output?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I fixed the problem though, but I needed to wait a few hours before I could answer a question that I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply restarted my device and it started working again. I guess the problem isn't in the code or project setting or properties list as I thought it would be.